# palpay checkout payment integration in php

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, paypal

I want to move from sandbox to live payment but when I click on paypal button nothing happens, every thing worked fine on sandbox. The Code is as follow:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Ac1JtK2cce52WagDVLQN1oTpq4c180RyAVRh6yYQBJNr-DPPVgMrCAZuM9h1s6-re06Whz2JRLZjXNdI&currency=USD"></script>
paypal.Buttons({
    
        // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked https://api-m.paypal.com

        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            
          return actions.order.create({

            purchase_units: [{

              amount: {

                value: document.getElementById('amount').value // Can also reference a variable or function

              }

            }]

          });

        },
        

        // Finalize the transaction after payer approval

        onApprove: (data, actions) => {

          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

            window.open('verify_transactions.php','_self');

          });

        }

      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```